Is there a reason why my code skips lines?
so i have this java code:
String line;
int numrow=5, numcol=5;
BufferedReader reader;
String arr[][]=new String [numrow][numcol];
try{
    reader=new BufferedReader (new FileReader(pname));
    int row=0;
    int col=0;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        if(line.startsWith("Entry")){
            col=0;
            line=reader.readLine();
            while(line!=null&&!line.startsWith("Entry")&&col<numcol){
                arr[row][col]=line;
                col++;
                line=reader.readLine();
            }
        row++;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
}
}

which is meant to take entries from a file with the format:
Entry 1:
a
a
a
a
a
Entry 2:
b
b
b
b
b
Entry 3:
c
c
c
c
c
Entry 4:
d
d
d
d
d
Entry 5:
e
e
e
e
e

and send them to a 2d array with the format
a a a a a
b b b b b
c c c c c
d d d d d
e e e e e

I tried the above code but it prints out like:
a a a a a  
c c c c c
e e e e e
null null null null null
null null null null null

what should i do to fix it?
(my print array code is below but it doesnt have any problem printing out another array)
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}


Your code should be creating 5 arrays. [][]means an array of arrays

Your inner line reading reads the Entry, then exits and you read a new line again which doesn’t match Entry again and skips lines. This is a good time to learn to use a debugger to run code line by line to find out what’s happening.

Your line reading can be simplified to help see what's happening here:
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // (1)
  if (line.startsWith("Entry")) {
    line = reader.readLine(); // (2)
    while (line != null && !line.startsWith("Entry")) {
      line = reader.readLine(); // (3)
    }
  }
}

Think about what happens when you read "Entry" at (3). The nested loop will break and the outer loop will go to the next iteration. But that next iteration starts by reading another line at (1), meaning the "Entry" you read at (3) is skipped (i.e., it will not be handled by the if block). Which means the outer loop will continue to iterate until the next "Entry", thus skipping an entire sequence of letters. Hence the pattern of skipping every other sequence of letters.
You need to avoid reading another line immediately after reading "Entry". Something like:
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if (line.startsWith("Entry")) {
    // update row and column positions for next entry
  } else {
    // put line in the array, increment column position
  }
}


When you run into issues like this, I recommend you use a debugger to step through the code. If you don't know how to use a debugger, then now is a great time to learn. That said, this code feels like a school/university assignment, and I know some curriculums prefer students wait to use debuggers until they know the fundamentals of programming. In such cases, there are other techniques you can use, such as printing messages to the console. Your code is also simple enough that you could debug it "by hand" (i.e., logically think through what the code is doing and keep track of the value of each variable at a given step in the algorithm).

thank you, i still have not learned how to use a debugger and yes this is a school assignment so using a debugger is not allowed. For now i have used printing to console and gotten more clarification on what is going on and how to understand what the computer is doing. I solved the problem thanks to you and other commenters, thank you for your help!

After reading 5th a, line would be Entry: 2 which will fail the inner while loop condition.
So now, back to outer while loop, within that condition check line=reader.readLine(), you are reading and reassigning line which value is b.
This will fail the if(line.startsWith("Entry")) and won't be assigned to your arrays.
This repeats for all the b, then it reads Entry 3: which satisfies the if condition and reads all the c and assigns it to your arrays.
Same thing repeats for d as well.

thank you for this insight, im still new to coding so i didn't really know to "think like a computer" and this helped me understand what the problem was, for the longest time i  was fixing my printing method but this helped me solve it. thank you!

If you take on board the comment here then an actual implementation that takes that into account makes the code somewhat clearer:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FiveFive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = null;
        int numrow = 5, numcol = 5;
        String arr[][] = new String[numrow][];
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0]))) {
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;
            String[] currArray = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("Entry")) {
                    currArray = new String[5];
                    arr[row++] = currArray;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numcol; i++) {
                    currArray[i] = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }
}

With your data, outputs:

[[a, a, a, a, a], [b, b, b, b, b], [c, c, c, c, c], [d, d, d, d, d], [e, e, e, e, e]]


In the 'real world' you're more likely to use Lists than arrays. Here's one way of doing it with a preview feature of Java 22. You need to compile with javac --enable-preview --release 22 GatherNestedStringList.java and run with java --enable-preview  GatherNestedStringList data.txt:
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Gatherers;

public class GatherNestedStringList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final int ROW_SIZE = 5;
        List<List<String>> matrix = null;
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0]))).useDelimiter("\\R")) {
            matrix = s.tokens().
                filter(line ->!line.startsWith("Entry")).
                gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(ROW_SIZE)).toList();
        }
        matrix.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

Prints

[a, a, a, a, a]
[b, b, b, b, b]
[c, c, c, c, c]
[d, d, d, d, d]
[e, e, e, e, e]


thank you for this approach, i never would have thought of making a second array and copying it from there! thank you

You've got six arrays. Five arrays plus one array of all those five

I've put another curiosity in there too
